# aws s3 bucket policy - allow range of ip addresses

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, policy, bucket

I am trying to allow access to a number of ipv4 ip addresses starting with 111.222 via a policy in aws s3, I have tried all the following but unable to get it to work -

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "AllowAccess",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "111.222.0.0",
                        "111.222.*.*",
            "111.222.."
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Is it possible to do this?  I want ip addresses such as 111.222.1.2 and 111.222.99.6 to have access.

The bucket is hosting a static website that doesn't allow public access.

If I put in the full ip address it works e.g. - 111.222.1.2 but there are hundreds of ip addresses, so would like to use a wildcard.

Comment: Ranges of adjacent IP addresses are typically allocated in blocks and expressed in CIDR notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CIDR as ip address.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "AllowAccess",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "111.222.0.0/16"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [this doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition_operators.html),

> IP address condition operators let you construct Condition elements that restrict access based on comparing a key to an IPv4 or IPv6 address or range of IP addresses. You use these with the aws:SourceIp key. The value must be in the standard CIDR format (for example, 203.0.113.0/24 or 2001:DB8:1234:5678::/64). If you specify an IP address without the associated routing prefix, IAM uses the default prefix value of /32.

You don't use wildcards in these condtions, you use Cidr notation.  From what you're saying, the wildcard equivalent of what you want seems to be `111.222.*.*` where `*` can be any number 0-255.  This is the CIDR `111.222.0.0/16`.